# Why is my form not submitting data into my database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have ensured this page is connecting to my database, but for some reason it is not submitting any data into the database and I'm not sure why.

I am fairly new to PHP and MYSQL, so any help would be appreciated.

If there is a better/more secure way, any information would help, as all the research I've found online/tutorials suggest different approaches.

I'm simply trying to create a register page, that submits data into my local MYSQL server.

```
<?php
require_once "connection.php";

session_start();  //intiate session for current user on site 

if (isset($_SESSION["email"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
   
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email");
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password");
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


//database entry
$create_account = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email,password) VALUES (:email, :password)");
$create_account->bindParam(':email', $email);
$create_account->bindParam(':password', $hashed_password);
$create_account->execute();

}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Food Roulette</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body class="colorThis">
    <div class="error"></div>
    <div class="oneForm">
        <form action="index.php" id="signupForm" method="POST">
            <h1 class="register"> Register now </h1><br>
            <label class="emailOne" for="email"> Email Address </label><br>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>

            <label class="passwordOne" for="password"> Password </label><br>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>
            <button class="registerBtn" name="register_button"> Login </button>
        </form>
    </div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#signUpForm').submit(function() {
            $.post("register.php", $("#signupForm").serialize(), function(data) {});
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

connection.php

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'getrecipes';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,//fetches row
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db";
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Have you created a separate user and password for database access?  Using "root"  is not particularly a good idea.  Also, iirc, by default mysql doesn't permit 'root' accessing the database from anywhere other than localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! I have not created a separate user and password for database access.

Comment: Then it would be a good idea to do that.  Create a specific user and password just for the database.  *Never* use ```root``` credentials anywhere other than on the localhost.

Comment: ok thank you, I will do that now

Comment: 1. Please move `session_start();`  to the top of the script (right after <?php (so will be `<?php session_start();` for the 1st line ) 2. I cannot see any assignment of values to $_SESSION["email"] and $_SESSION["password"] , so the 1st conditional block (containing the insert query) may never be executed .

Comment: Thanks for the help, ewong and Ken, the issue has now been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes thanks to the help in the comments, and further research.

I can now submit data to the database.

To prevent the form from submitting after refreshing the page, I have added a script

```
<?php 
session_start();

require_once "connection.php";

//intiate session for current user on site 

if (isset($_SESSION)){

    if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password");
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    //database entry
    $create_account = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email,password) VALUES (:email, :password)");
    $create_account->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $create_account->bindParam(':password', $hashed_password);
    $create_account->execute();

    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Food Roulette</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body class="colorThis">
    <div class="error"></div>
    <div class="oneForm">
        <form action="" id="signupForm" method="POST">
            <h1 class="register"> Register now </h1><br>
            <label class="emailOne" for="email"> Email Address </label><br>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>

            <label class="passwordOne" for="password"> Password </label><br>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>
            <button class="registerBtn" name="register_button"> Login </button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
 <script>
        if (window.history.replaceState) {
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```